# How To Minimize The Main Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have Main Form with border and other forms are borderless in a project. I have modeling it but I am facing problem of not minimize the forms.

When main form open then it allow to close , minimize and maximize button but if I open another forms from main form then it not allow. The close,minimize and maximize button are being disable at time of open other borderless forms from main form.

I wants  to allow minimize and disable maximize and close button while opening of the new borderless forms from main forms.

How to do?.

### Follow To LarseTech Answer(Question):

---

Comment: Hard to read this, but it sounds like your close-min-max buttons are enabled, but if you are opening these borderless forms, they are being disabled?

Comment: That does not happen by itself.  I'm guessing somewhere in your code you have `mainForm.MinimizeBox = false;`  Try finding it and commenting it out.

Comment: @LarsTech, It's Reality, and for that you have to create a simple project with two forms, one is main with border and other is borderless forms and allow to open it from main form and see what happen

Comment: okay, I did that.  My main form min-max buttons are still enabled.

Comment: @LarsTech, but it's not working the same thing in my case, there may be reason of version of VS. I am using VS-2005

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13956/discussion-between-mahesh-and-larstech)

Answer (score 2):

As per the discussion in chat:

```
f2.ShowDialog(this);
```

makes the child form a modal form, and it will block access to the main form until it is closed.

Try changing it to:

```
f2.Show(this);
```

As far as child forms showing up in the ALT-Tab list, I can only guess that WinXP does that.  In Win7, the borderless child forms did not appear in the ALT-Tab list.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the System.Windows.Forms.Form.WindowState property to FormWindowState.Minimized.

You can do this from the form desginer

Comment: You mean to alter the value of FormWindowState property from Maximise to minimized at GUI Environment. If yes then my friend it not allow to display anything as I designed the main form as per maximise mode.